# Best strategy for picking accuracy priority for Fused Location Services?

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location

I'm building an app that requires that location coordinates be recorded every 5 minutes. Because the devices I'm targeting are Samsung devices, which has a problem with getting from network providers via the native Android location library, I have opted to use the Fused Location Services from the Google Play Services.

Obviously using `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` would be best as it would use all providers to get the best location. The problem is that this drains the battery too quickly. I'd like to toggle between `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` and `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`, depending on the situation.

Currently, I have it so when there is internet connection (confirmed by pinging a specific site), I use `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY`. If there isn't, I use `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`. I'm wondering if this is the best way, as there could be situations where the user is not connected to any WIFI, but has their WIFI on and is in a WIFI crowded area. Should I, in addition to checking for connectivity, if that fails, check for available WIFI access points  and if I find some, still use `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY`?

Comment: Huy, i would love to hear about your "problem with getting from network providers via the native Android location library". I have a location based app and we're having issues with Samsung phones as well. We switched to fused however, and we're still seeing them sometimes. What kind of issues are you experiencing? Is there some resource somewhere you could point to? Input would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you run a thread or intent service which runs periodically checking the battery level of the app. when the level falls below a certain threshold, call removeLocationUpdates()  and register again by calling requestLocationUpdates() with a LocationRequest object with 'PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY'

Also, you can check if the user is in a Wi-Fi crowded area using WifiManager Class where you can scan for wifi hotspots using startScan() and register for the results in a broadcast receiver and make changes depending on the result.

I don't think it is possible to determine if the user is indoors. The gps signal is usually weaker indoors and you could probably use the GpsStatus class and getSatellites() method to infer some knowledge about that.

Answer (score 0):

How flexible is your 5 minute requirement?  I'm not sure if this would be feasible for your application but you may want to allow the user to select the accuracy for themselves in a settings menu.  You can offer a low power option and a high accuracy option that uses the `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` and P`RIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` respectively.  Another option is to provide a slider so the user can set the interval time between location updates and use `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` for long intervals and `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` for short intervals.

Comment: The 5 minute requirement is a must. As for letting the user decide, lets just say the user base I'm making this app for isn't technologically responsible enough to depend on to make the right decision. I basically want to be able to sense if they are inside, to use PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY (as it has pretty good accuracy indoors without the battery drain) and when they are outside, it uses PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY to include the GPS provider. Is there any strategy to sense if a device is indoor or outdoors?